# Flutter: Assign Variable With String Only If Value Is Not Null

Tags: flutter, dart, null, dart-null-safety

I want to assign a variable only if the value is not null. However, I also need an extra string added to the variable to be used in video overlays (so need the extra `min` in this case). So I need `minVal` to return null if `$time` is null or return `$time min` if $time is populated. Currently, if $time is null, it still recognizes the "min" and is returning "min".

```
final minVal = '$time min' ?? null;
```

The code below works in returning null if `$time` is null, but I need the extra "min" string to be added somewhere. Any ideas?

```
final minVal = '$time' ?? null;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check if $time is null or not using ternary operator

```
final minVal = time != null ? '$time min' : null;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That seems to still be returning `min` even if `$time` is null.

Comment: SOrry forgot to remove `$` in the comaprision. Updated the answer

Comment: Thank for your help! I realized I was also using an older version of Flutter still in this project (no null safety). This is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
String ? myVariable;
Text("${myVariable!=null?myVariable:""}");
```

if myVariable values is not equals null then return value else make null safety